# Native library loads, but calling native function throws UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface

I built a native library, `libmynative.so`, that exposes a single, straightforward function:

```java
public class MyWrapper {
    public static native double MyCalculation(double a, double b);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mynative");
    }
}
```

This works fine when I compile MyWrapper.java, have the .so and .class files together, and run a simple test with `java -Djava.library.path=. MyWrapper` (when this class has a `main` method).

But I want to package both the wrapper and native library into a .jar file and use it by having the wrapper extract the .so file and load it from a temp directory at runtime. My code is basically:

```java
public class MyWrapper {
    public static native double MyCalculation(double a, double b);

    private static File tempDir = null;

    static {
        try {
           tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("foo").toFile();
           tempDir.deleteOnExit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Couldn't create temporary directory");
        }

        try {
            InputStream inStream = OpenDP.class.getResourceAsStream("/libmynative.so");

            // Create the temp file in the filesystem
            File temp = new File(tempDir.getPath() + "/libmynative.so");
            temp.createNewFile();
            temp.deleteOnExit();
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);

            // Copy from the .jar to the filesystem
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } finally {
                outStream.close();
                inStream.close();
            }

            // Try to load library from extracted native resources
            String p = tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/libmynative.so";
            System.load(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I can call my native function in a standalone app, so the function signature is fine.

I build a jar file with MyWrapper.class in its package directory and libmynative.so in the root. Then I have a simple test project that I run (using `java -cp ".:MyJar.jar" MyTestProject`):

```
import com.myorganization.MyWrapper;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MyWrapper.MyCalculation(1.0, 2.0));
}
```

This fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.myorganization.MyWrapper.MyCalculation(DD)D
        at com.myorganization.MyWrapper.MyCalculation(NativeMethod)
        ...
```

I've verified that the `System.load` call doesn't throw an exception; the problem occurs when the function is invoked. My best guess, not being an expert here, is that there's an issue with the `java.library.path` which isn't set? How can I debug what's going on here? Or is there a simple answer?

Comment: No, the issue is with the .so not containing a method with a signature corresponding to the Java native method signature. That's what this exception means. NB You don't need `temp.createNewFile()` here. It is just a waste of time and space. `new FileOutputStream()` will delete that file and create its own, and you are doubling directory searching as well. NB 2 You're not going to be able to delete the directory `foo` unless you delete the .so file, and you won't be able to delete that at all as it is still loaded.

Comment: "the issue is with the .so not containing a method with a signature corresponding to the Java native method signature" -- why does a standalone java app work but one that calls the jar doesn't? What would need to change?

Comment: Maybe you loaded the wrong .so file. Maybe you corrupted it somehow. The point is that this is not a viable distribution strategy. Reconsider.

Comment: Speculating that it's corrupt isn't helpful: I've confirmed that the .so is not corrupt by using it in a simple java app outside of the jar. The distribution strategy is also apparently common.

Comment: Have you compared the copied .so file against the original one to verify that they are identical byte-for-byte? Have you checked whether `JNI_OnLoad` gets executed?

Comment: Speculating that it's corrupt is extremely helpful actually, unless there is a cognitive bias present. It may not be the answer, but I also suggested two other possibilities, neither of which you have addressed.

Comment: To be sure that your copying code is not responsible, drop it and use built-in features: [`File temp = new File(tempDir, "libmynative.so"); try(InputStream inStream = OpenDP.class.getResourceAsStream("/libmynative.so")) { Files.copy(inStream, temp.toPath()); temp.deleteOnExit(); } System.load(temp.getAbsolutePath());`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

Comment: The fact that the library loads successfully, and the linkage error occurs when the function is looked up, makes me think it's very unlikely that the library file is corrupted. `System.load` doesn't use `java.library.path` so there should be no issue there.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the name of the function that Java expects is not the name of the function inside the library.

You can use the `-Xlog:library=info` VM flag (JDK 15+) to see which symbol the JVM is actually trying to load. Since you're getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` it should print something like this at the end:

```
[0.622s][info][library] Failed to find Java_my_package_MyWrapper_MyCalculation in library with handle 0x00007ff8a24f0000
```

Then, you can use `nm` to make sure that that symbol is actually in the library:

```
nm libmynative.so | grep Java_my_package_MyWrapper_MyCalculation
```

And I'm guessing you'll find that it isn't.

The solution in that case is to change the name of the function in the library to be what Java expects. One way to do that is to regenerate the header file with `javah` or `javac -h`, which will have the right name, and then implement the function from that header file.